# Change navigation style when within certain area of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building a website that has a navigation fixed to the top of the window and all content for the website is on one page it is just split into sections as you move down the window, or if you click on a navigation button it will scroll you to that point on the page (vertically).

What i'm trying to achieve is for the navigation to change to an 'active' style/class when the user is within that section of the window, using jQuery if possible.

Does anyone know how i would go about this?

Each section of the website is contained within it's own div with its own id so maybe something can be done using that, or could i maybe do it that if the top of the screen is within a certain pixel range of the window height?

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great, thanks J.

Comment: Twitter bootstrap has this functionality using https://github.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inview plugin, which let you do stuff when a certain element is scrolled into 
the window

[Try this](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview)

Comment: Thanks that works well, just need a bit of tweeking abd should be there.